# Running PHP server and MySQL on iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, apache, web

Is there any possibility of running a PHP server (lighttpd, apache, cherokee, etc) and a MySQL server (or sqlite) on a non-jailbroken iOS device? I know about http://www.becomekodiak.com/ and they seem to be running a server (or just an interpreter?), but there is no database connection.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cocoahttpserver, iPhoneHTTPServer3, SimpleWebSocketServer, MultithreadedHTTPServer3 or MongooseDaemon to realize the Server. The content generation is being made by your code and you could use CoreData or any other mobile database solution to save and provide the data.

It's no PHP, but you could implement it in Objective C.